# After killing on VATS mode, I'm waiting for the kill cam to end, but my enemies aren't!

Tags: fallout-4

The situation is this:
I'm attacked by a bunch of enemies, so I go in VATS mode and plan a sequence of shots for a few ones. When I kill one, by the time I target the next one, I'm in slow motion kill cam. But, my enemies are still moving so they can attack me when I'm waiting for the slow motion kill cam to end.

I don't know if there is a setting to avoid this. So my question is:
Is there a way to avoid my character waiting?

Comment: I would assume there isn't a setting for that, PC or otherwise.  If you are in slow motion, the rest of the world is supposed to be too.

Comment: I can't tell for sure based on your description, but it sounds like you are only targeting one person at a time.  You can target multiple people in one go with VATS.  If this is the case, I think your game is experiencing some sort of bug then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're in VATS mode, both you and the enemies should be in slow motion. If not, then there's a glitch occurring.

But, it sounds like you're just having a problem waiting for the kill cam to end so you can kill the next thing.

This is fixable. If you tap the VATS button during the kill cam, it will exit and you can continue doing things. The cancel button (B on Xbox) will also exit VATS. I often skip out of that kill cam and line up the next shot before the bullet gets there. This is because, even if no glitch is occurring, the enemies keep moving in slow motion while you sit there and do nothing watching your bullet.

To minimize the time spent out of VATS, tap the button to exit, then immediately hold the button to re-enter it. If you keep tapping the button, you're liable to enter and immediately re-exit, which can be bad news. Remember that you have 90% damage reduction while in VATS.

One specific time I do this on every playthrough is when fighting Kellog. I line up a crit with the fat man from the armory, fire it, and then cancel out and set up VATS shots on the synths before the mini-nuke hits Kellog.

Comment: Totally forgot about that trick.  I do it all the time to skip the kill cam.  It's like muscle memory at this point, which is why I forgot about it.

Comment: I just use the B button (console). As soon as you shoot your bullet or whatever, like literally even before you see the bullet hit the target (because of slow mo) you can leave VATs, then reenter VATs, choose a new target, etc... faster than waiting for VATs to do more than one attack in a row, depending on the weapon you're using.

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites That's what I'm saying to do. I guess the B button would probably work as well.

Comment: Yeah I was just adding that the B button also worked. I didn't know the VATs button also worked so I figured maybe others didn't know the B button works. :)

Comment: Some side notes that might help... 1. Make sure you reload before using VATS (watch https://goo.gl/FQyKj4 for epic laughs) and 2. While in VATs you have huge, huge damage reduction, so if the enemies are attacking you it might be better to remain in VATs anyway to receive less damage. (To test this feel free to "melee" attack a frag mine using VATs. So long as you can swing 2-3 times, long enough for the mine to detonate while you're /in/ VATs, then you'll survive just fine. Won't even notice the scratch! In survival the same mine that one shots me does only 20% damage while I'm in VATs)

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites You have 90% damage reduction in VATS. The transition in and out of VATS should be nearly instant.

Comment: Nearly... hahahaha... tell that to my Xbone when I accidentally VATs a basic turret (in during 3-5 fps) xD That being said, 90% is pretty powerful. I guess that means that frag mine could have done 200% of my HP if it only took away 20%. So, 1 mine can kill me twice while I'm out of VATs, but it would take /5/ mines to kill me in VATs. That's good!